# Finding the Inverse Function of a Logarithmic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The equation is $y=-\log_2(x+3)+4$ . I have to find the inverse function but I am not sure how to do it. I worked it out but when I went to check it, it wouldn't work out so please help and show steps.

Comment: How do you find inverse functions in general? Why did your work not check out?

Comment: I switched x and y like my teacher told me to do, so x=-log_(2)(y+3)+4 and then worked it out and got y=2^(-x+4)-3. Either I worked it out wrong or am checking it wrong

Comment: Okay, but then what?

Comment: x=-log_(2)(y+3)+4, then I subtracted 4 to get x-4=-log_(2)(y+3)+4, multplied both sides by -1, and used the logarithmic property log_(b)(x)--> b^y=x and got 2^(-x+4)=y+3, and then subtracted 3 to finally get y=2^(-x+4)-3

Comment: And so what's the issue?

Comment: I guess I may have checked it wrong when I plugged the points in. So I am correct? it is y=2^(-x+4)-3?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Have you not learnt how to do it yet? You have asked so many of these questions; you should have at least a little bit of an idea of how to do it

Comment: Not really, my teacher has been absent for a the past few days and decided to throw a test at us tomorrow. I am starting to figure it out, but just need reassurance that I am doing it right and am understanding it

Comment: At least you know how to do it now, your answer in the comments is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to find the inverse of
$$y=-\log_2(x+3)+4$$
You know the drill; swap $x$ and $y$, and solve for $y$
$$x=-\log_2(y+3)+4$$
I don't like the negative in front of logarithm.
$$\log_2(y+3)-4=-x$$
$$\log_2(y+3)=4-x$$
If $\log_a(b)=c$, then $a^c=b$.
$$y+3=2^{4-x}$$
$$y=2^{4-x}-3$$
Change $y$ to $f^{-1}(x)$
$$\color{green}{\boxed{f^{-1}(x)=2^{4-x}-3}}$$

Answer (score 1):

You have a function in $x$, $y(x)=-\log_2(x+3)+4\; \forall x>-3$.

You are looking for a function in $x$, $z(x)>-3$ such that $y(z(x))=x$.

Hence, $-\log_2(z(x)+3)+4=x$.

Now get $z(x)$ out. $z(x)=2^{4-x}-3$.

Comment: You are welcome.